# Data frame in pandas in python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, join

I am performing outer join on two data frames both have columns 
'index', 'author', 'body', 'subreddit', 'subreddit_id', 'score'

and I am trying to overlap columns using lsuffix and rsuffix but it give error

```
neither_df = chunk.set_index('author').join(both_authors.set_index('author'), on='author', how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right').reset_index()
    columnsNamesArr = neither_df.columns.values
    listOfColumnNames = list(columnsNamesArr)
    print("List Of Column Names" , listOfColumnNames)
```

and output is

```
list of columns ['index', 'author', 'body', 'subreddit', 'subreddit_id', 'score']
```

Comment: Hey Nimra, can you post a sample of your data and your expected output?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Datanovice yes i want my output for neither. df  as : list of columns ['author', 'author_left', 'body', 'subreddit', 'subreddit_id', 'score',author_right']